# Oracle's specification or SQL's ? : Truncate table with foreign key constraints

Tags: oracle, truncate

I want to see a specification about "Truncate table with foreign key constraints" like below. Does anyone know where it is defined ?

> On the minus side, if you have a foreign key constraint referring to
>   the table you are trying to truncate, this won't work - even if the
>   referring table has no data in it! This is because the foreign key
>   checking is done with DDL rather than DML. This can be got around by
>   temporarily disabling the foreign key constraint(s) to the table.
>   http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands

Answer (score 2):

You mean the fourth bullet in the restrictions on truncating tables section of the [Oracle's `truncate` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10007.htm#CHDDGIHF)?

> You cannot truncate the parent table of an enabled foreign key
>   constraint. You must disable the constraint before truncating the
>   table. An exception is that you can truncate the table if the
>   integrity constraint is self-referential.

Comment: This's it! but it does not mention about "no data" condition explicitly. If you know that please teach me.

Comment: @yusaku - it *doesn't* say 'unless the child table contains no data`, it's a blanket statement that you just can't ever do it. It's (strongly, IMO) implied that it *does* mean 'even if there is no data'. As the orafaq link says, that's because it's a DDL statement. Making it look at data in the table you're truncating, never mind any tables that reference it, would mean it had to do DML as well, changing its nature, and it would lose some of the efficiency advantages - as pure DDL it doesn't have to retrieve any data at all (outside the data dictionary itself).