# Is truncation of parent table restricted even when child table is empty?

Tags: oracle, parent-child, truncate, cascading-deletes

I can use `delete from table_name` which works.
Why not `truncate`?

Comment: Foreign-key reference... second-half of your answer...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9519432

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <tablename>;
```

after disabling the FK constraint.

Truncating cannot be rolled back as it is [DDL rather than DML](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands) so be careful.
It also resets the highwater mark of the table being truncated.

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10006.htm) for the Oracle docs explanation.
and [here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands) for a comparison.

N.B.: **You cannot truncate the parent table of an enabled foreign key constraint. You must disable the constraint before truncating the table. An exception is that you can truncate the table if the integrity constraint is self-referential.**

From the [Oracle documantation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm).

Hope it helps...

Comment: `TRUNCATE` also resets identity columns

Comment: @ntziolis: Oracle doesn't have "identity" columns.